Handling menu borders with ToolStripProfessionalRenderer (C#, Winforms

I have this customized menu with ToolStripProfessionalRenderer and my intention would be to customize the border to better fit the menu. What you now see is the basic winforms color for the border, only it looks much lighter than it is because of the black background. So, basically, when you have a normal color for the menu you don't see actually the upper border because the first menu item and subitem have the same backcolor as this border color but now that I changed those to a black color I need to change at least the upper border color to their same color. So, how do you think that can be achieved? I thought I could handle the single items backcolor but it looks like it's not the case, as the dropdown menu border color is not part of the single items.

You also need to create a custom ProfessionalColorTable to provide the desired colors. The renderer will use them to render the different parts of the ToolStrip controls family.  The MenuBorder property is what you need to override to return Color.Black (or even Color.Empty) instead of the default color. See this answer for example.

How to change white line on left edge of dropdown items? - Change the border color of Winforms menu dropdown list

Some useful links you managed to find, thank you so much!
